# PowerBI parse delimited data

Tags: json, csv, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table containing other tables in its values. These other tables can be formatted either as CSV or JSON.

Can you please tell me how I can import this data into individual tables in PowerBI? I've tried with the PowerQuery GUI but so far unsuccessfully, perhaps there will be a need to use the code in the advanced editor.

I can't just parse this data outside PowerBI because of company guidelines prohibiting the use of scripts, so everything must be done within PowerBI - though the PowerQuery code is allowed.

1. csv:
   `"id,normdist,poissondist,binomial\r\n1,0.00013383,0.033689735,0.009765625\r\n2,0.004431848,0.084224337,0.043945313\r\n3,0.053990967,0.140373896,0.1171875\r\n4,0.241970725,0.17546737,0.205078125\r\n5,0.39894228,0.17546737,0.24609375\r\n6,0.241970725,0.146222808,0.205078125\r\n7,0.053990967,0.104444863,0.1171875\r\n8,0.004431848,0.065278039,0.043945313\r\n9,0.00013383,0.036265577,0.009765625\r\n10,1.49E-06,0.018132789,0.000976563\r\n"`
2. json (by row)

`[{"id":1,"normdist":0.0001,"poissondist":0.0337,"binomial":0.0098},{"id":2,"normdist":0.0044,"poissondist":0.0842,"binomial":0.0439},{"id":3,"normdist":0.054,"poissondist":0.1404,"binomial":0.1172},{"id":4,"normdist":0.242,"poissondist":0.1755,"binomial":0.2051},{"id":5,"normdist":0.3989,"poissondist":0.1755,"binomial":0.2461},{"id":6,"normdist":0.242,"poissondist":0.1462,"binomial":0.2051},{"id":7,"normdist":0.054,"poissondist":0.1044,"binomial":0.1172},{"id":8,"normdist":0.0044,"poissondist":0.0653,"binomial":0.0439},{"id":9,"normdist":0.0001,"poissondist":0.0363,"binomial":0.0098},{"id":10,"normdist":1.49e-06,"poissondist":0.0181,"binomial":0.001}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the data is in the CSV version but just a string in a database so that it looks like this in the query editor:

[image: Cell]

In order to expand this into a table, we need to split it into rows and columns. The Home tab has a Split Column tool we'll use like this using By Delimiter option from the dropdown:

[image: Split into Rows]

That is, we use "\r\n" to split the cell into multiple rows.

Now our column looks like this:

[image: Split Result]

Remove any blank rows and use the Split Column tool again. This time, you can leave the defaults since it will automatically guess that you want to split by comma and expand into rows.

If you promote the headers and clean up the column types, the final result should be

[image: Result]

---

Full M Query for this example that you can paste into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("7ZFJbsMwDEXvkrUacBKHA/QUcRYpshHQ2EXc+6OS4mzkC3Th3Qf5+ThdLqdyT/PyfNzL+pt+lrKuy9z1V5mXR7l9T9NzmmZMcAYAZHZuklk9jHMPh2lWyi8n9ZAIo4s37UIkzNa0cEhm5Je1kzJHQGhLowAbe2jTaOi2MaUGSDAMjFpLtCxqHUmQwRzf3VuWw6P29MEoCsFvoo5EUaol4HukjVPW5URceZzSx801kzlw7DeP8ZxKmrPZ/pwICc8Snx/QRgZ05Ard6rtzQ56u6Xjm8czjmf/wmdc/", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Split by \r\n into Rows" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("\r\n", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Filtered Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split by \r\n into Rows", each [Column1] <> null and [Column1] <> ""),
    #"Split into Columns" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Blank Rows", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Split into Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Filtered Repeated Headers" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each ([id] <> "id")),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Repeated Headers",{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"normdist", type number}, {"poissondist", type number}, {"binomial", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: the csv is not in a file, but it is in a database. this csv is contained into a cell which is in a database, hence my need for import.

Comment: So is it actually a CSV file then or is it just text stored in a database cell?

Comment: Text stored in a db cell

Comment: In that case, you'll want to use the Split Column (by delimiter) tool. First split by "\r\n" into rows and the by "," into columns. (Gotta run. I'll try to update later.)

Comment: yes, this works. thanks, please update and I'll accept.